# can I use USSD messages in the background without the pop-up message showing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ussd

I am starting to develop a cross-platform mobile app and I want to use the USSD , I am using JavaScript/HTML5/JQuery and I wonder if I can use the USSD messages contents without the pop-up message , I am reading that the new version of android cancelled the support of the USSD API . can I proceed using USSD in my cross platform project or do I need to consider doing it natively on each platform .

Answer (score 0):

DEFINETLY you can't do this..

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285

I had done lots and lots of try regarding this... but i wonder how `USSDChecker` app alone doing this without any flaw...